# Why this simple REST application deploys/runs successfully to Tomee Plume 8.0.0-M2, but, *not* to Tomee Microprofile 8.0.0-M2?

Tags: rest, java-11, tomee-8

Why does this simple REST application deploys successfully to Tomee Plume 8.0.0-M2, but, will NOT successfully deploy to Tomee Microprofile 8.0.0-M2?

MICROPROFILE deployment (fails):

```
-
-
-
21-Jun-2019 15:50:59.688 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 15:50:59.690 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracting jar: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0.war
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.340 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracted path: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.341 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.session.manager=org.apache.tomee.catalina.session.QuickSessionManager'
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.820 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.955 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.955 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean jjwtrest-1.0.0.Comp563734597: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.955 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.962 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.core.managed.SimplePassivater.init Using directory C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\temp for stateful session passivation
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.984 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0" loaded.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:00.990 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.051 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initSingleton Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@681a8b4e
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.120 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.126 INFO [main] org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader.startUp Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.267 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.handleBda Using annotated mode for jar:file:/C:/tools/jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS/target/.distribution/apache-tomee/lib/geronimo-config-impl-1.2.1.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml looking all classes to find CDI beans, maybe think to add a beans.xml if not there or add the jar to exclusions.list
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.301 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.handleBda Using annotated mode for file:/C:/tools/jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS/target/.distribution/apache-tomee/lib/microprofile-rest-client-api-1.1.jar looking all classes to find CDI beans, maybe think to add a beans.xml if not there or add the jar to exclusions.list
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.917 INFO [main] org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints All injection points were validated successfully.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.944 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 824 ms.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:01.956 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0)
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.047 INFO [main] org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer.onStartup Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.059 SEVERE [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jjwtrest-1.0.0]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader @4565a70a (instance of org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader, child of java.net.URLClassLoader @34cd072c java.net.URLClassLoader) wants to load abstract class javax.faces.context.ExternalContext. A different abstract class with the same name was previously loaded by java.net.URLClassLoader @34cd072c (instance of java.net.URLClassLoader, child of 'app' jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader).
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:833)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1278)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
        at org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEFacesConfigResourceProviderFactory.resolveFacesConfigResourceProviderFromService(TomEEFacesConfigResourceProviderFactory.java:65)
        at org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEFacesConfigResourceProviderFactory.createFacesConfigResourceProvider(TomEEFacesConfigResourceProviderFactory.java:50)
        at org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer.isFacesConfigPresent(MyFacesContainerInitializer.java:333)
        at org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer.onStartup(MyFacesContainerInitializer.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.059 SEVERE [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error deploying web application archive [C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jjwtrest-1.0.0]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.060 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application archive [C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0.war] has finished in [2,377] ms
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesRmiTargets] to [true] as the property does not exist.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [skipMemoryLeakChecksOnJvmShutdown] to [false] as the property does not exist.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.441 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [367] milliseconds.
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.443 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.456 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Jun-2019 15:51:02.458 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 2836 ms
```

PLUME deployment (fine):

```
-
-
-
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.058 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.059 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracting jar: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0.war
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.466 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.JarExtractor.extract Extracted path: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.466 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.session.manager=org.apache.tomee.catalina.session.QuickSessionManager'
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.723 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.879 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.879 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig.createContainer Auto-creating a container for bean jjwtrest-1.0.0.Comp156855528: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.880 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.886 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.core.managed.SimplePassivater.init Using directory C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\temp for stateful session passivation
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.906 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0" loaded.
21-Jun-2019 17:21:19.910 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.037 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0)
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.198 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.402 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication Using readers:
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.402 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.PrimitiveTextProvider@61bb1e4d
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.403 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider@52559a69
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.403 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider@285583d4
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.403 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider@1039bfc4
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.403 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementTypedProvider@7f85217c
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.404 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider@1fd7a37
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.404 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonbProvider@7fedb795
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.404 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonpProvider@5c53f292
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.404 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider@46fb0c33
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.404 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider@3b009e7b
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.405 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider@270a620
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.405 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication Using writers:
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.405 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.WadlDocumentMessageBodyWriter@41f4039e
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.405 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.nio.NioMessageBodyWriter@5ff00507
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.405 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider@46fb0c33
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.405 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementTypedProvider@7f85217c
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.406 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.PrimitiveTextProvider@61bb1e4d
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.406 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider@52559a69
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.406 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider@285583d4
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.406 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider@1039bfc4
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.406 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider@1fd7a37
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.406 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonbProvider@7fedb795
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.407 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonpProvider@5c53f292
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.407 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider@3b009e7b
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.407 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider@270a620
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.407 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication Using exception mappers:
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.407 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper@cfd1075
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.408 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.EJBExceptionMapper@c1050f2
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.408 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper@45117dd
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.408 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener$CxfResponseValidationExceptionMapper@7741771e
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.410 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints REST Application: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/            -> org.apache.openejb.server.rest.InternalApplication@68ab6ab0
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.414 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/pet         -> Pojo aaa.bbb.ccc.war.JjwtRest
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.415 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/pet/{petId} ->      PetType getPetById(Long) throws Exception
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.445 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application archive [C:\tools\jjwtrest_STACKOVERFLOW_VERS\target\.distribution\apache-tomee\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0.war] has finished in [1,393] ms
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesRmiTargets] to [true] as the property does not exist.
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches] to [true] as the property does not exist.
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setClassLoaderProperty Unable to set the web application class loader property [skipMemoryLeakChecksOnJvmShutdown] to [false] as the property does not exist.
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.847 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [388] milliseconds.
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.849 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.854 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
21-Jun-2019 17:21:20.856 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 1876 ms
```

The rest service class:

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/pet")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public class JjwtRest {

    public JjwtRest() {
    }

    //curl -k -v -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/pet/33333
    @GET
    @Path("/{petId}")
    public PetType getPetById(@PathParam("petId") Long petId) throws Exception {

    //...just returning the same thing, no matter what...
    PetType newPet = new PetType();
    newPet.setId(11111);
    newPet.setName("Phoebe");
    return newPet;
    }
}
```

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwtrest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomee.classifier>plume</tomee.classifier>
    <tomee.version>8.0.0-M2</tomee.version>
    <javaee.api.version>8.0</javaee.api.version>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>    
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>        

    </dependencies>

    <name>jjwtrest</name>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <!--
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        -->
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>C:/toolsx/jdk-11.0.2/bin/javac</executable>
        </configuration> 
        </plugin>            

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <tomeeVersion>${tomee.version}</tomeeVersion>
            <tomeeClassifier>${tomee.classifier}</tomeeClassifier>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>executable-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>                        
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Environment:

Openjdk 11

REST

Tomee 8.0.0-M2  (Plume works,  Microprofile does *not* work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The fix required removal of...***

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee.api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

*(NOTE: I had earlier switched to using "compile" scope)*

***...and adding the following dependency***

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

***The entire pom.xml looks like this***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwtrest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <tomee.classifier>microprofile</tomee.classifier>
    <tomee.version>8.0.0-M2</tomee.version>
    <javaee.api.version>8.0</javaee.api.version>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>         
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>   
        <scope>compile</scope>                 
    </dependency> 

    </dependencies>

    <name>jjwtrest</name>
    <build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>C:/toolsx/jdk-11.0.2/bin/javac</executable>
        </configuration> 
        </plugin>            

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <tomeeVersion>${tomee.version}</tomeeVersion>
            <tomeeClassifier>${tomee.classifier}</tomeeClassifier>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>executable-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>                        
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*(Also, note:  the tomee-maven-plugin builds both a regular war file and generates an executable tomee "fat" jar, as well... Both work for either "plume" or (now) "microprofile"  Tomee versions...)*

***Fwiw, here is the "microprofile" console output snippet***

```
24-Jun-2019 15:05:41.897 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized MyFaces Core has started, it took [1029] ms.
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.460 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication Using readers:
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.462 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.PrimitiveTextProvider@75f9b939
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.463 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider@262a67d3
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.464 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider@7575373d
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.464 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider@3686e235
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.468 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementTypedProvider@2686aa18
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.468 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider@53e755e4
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.468 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonbProvider@4205cfa6
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.468 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonpProvider@2b374bb5
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.469 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider@16951525
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.469 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider@7c76480d
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.470 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider@44fe06cb
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.471 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication Using writers:
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.471 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.WadlDocumentMessageBodyWriter@55059702
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.472 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.nio.NioMessageBodyWriter@6b079cba
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.472 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider@16951525
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.472 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementTypedProvider@2686aa18
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.472 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.PrimitiveTextProvider@75f9b939
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.472 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider@262a67d3
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.481 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider@7575373d
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.481 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.openapi.jaxrs.JacksonOpenAPIYamlBodyWriter@25ff87f7
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.483 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider@3686e235
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.488 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider@53e755e4
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.489 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonbProvider@4205cfa6
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.489 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.johnzon.TomEEJsonpProvider@2b374bb5
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.489 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider@7c76480d
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.489 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider@44fe06cb
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.489 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication Using exception mappers:
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.490 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper@5651b37d
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.490 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.tomee.microprofile.jwt.MPJWTFilter$MPJWTExceptionMapper@15476be0
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.491 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.EJBExceptionMapper@1f754ec4
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.491 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper@fd98956
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.491 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployApplication      org.apache.tomee.microprofile.jwt.MPJWTFilter$MPJWTExceptionMapper@26045bde
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.499 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints REST Application: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/                            -> org.apache.openejb.server.rest.InternalApplication@6a95e0c4
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.507 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/health                      -> Pojo org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.common.jaxrs.HealthChecksEndpoint
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.507 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/health                      ->      Response getChecks()
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.510 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/health                      -> Pojo org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.impl.health.cdi.CdiHealthChecksEndpoint
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.510 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/health                      ->      Response getChecks()
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.519 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics                     -> Pojo org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.metrics.common.jaxrs.MetricsEndpoints
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.519 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics                     ->      Object getJson(SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.519 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics                     ->      String getText(SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.519 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}          ->      Object getJson(String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.520 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}          ->      String getText(String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.520 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}/{metric} ->      Object getJson(String, String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.520 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}/{metric} ->      String getText(String, String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.520 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints           OPTIONS http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}          ->      Object getMetadata(String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.520 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints           OPTIONS http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}/{metric} ->      Object getMetadata(String, String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.521 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics                     -> Pojo org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.metrics.jaxrs.CdiMetricsEndpoints
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.521 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics                     ->      Object getJson(SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.521 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics                     ->      String getText(SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.522 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}          ->      Object getJson(String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.522 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}          ->      String getText(String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.522 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}/{metric} ->      Object getJson(String, String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.522 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}/{metric} ->      String getText(String, String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.522 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints           OPTIONS http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}          ->      Object getMetadata(String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.523 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints           OPTIONS http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/metrics/{registry}/{metric} ->      Object getMetadata(String, String, SecurityContext, UriInfo)
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.523 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/openapi                     -> Pojo org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.openapi.jaxrs.OpenAPIEndpoint
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.523 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/openapi                     ->      OpenAPI get()
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.524 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints      Service URI: http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/pet                         -> Pojo aaa.bbb.ccc.war.JjwtRest   
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.524 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.logEndpoints               GET http://localhost:8084/jjwtrest-1.0.0/pet/{petId}                 ->      PetType getPetById(Long) throws Exception
24-Jun-2019 15:05:42.568 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application archive [C:\toolsx\apache-tomee-microprofile-8.0.0-M2\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0.war] has finished in [6,229] ms
24-Jun-2019 15:05:47.657 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
24-Jun-2019 15:05:48.184 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Jun-2019 15:05:48.729 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Stopping service [Catalina]
24-Jun-2019 15:05:48.756 INFO [Thread-16] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: C:\toolsx\apache-tomee-microprofile-8.0.0-M2\webapps\docs
24-Jun-2019 15:05:48.853 INFO [Thread-16] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: C:\toolsx\apache-tomee-microprofile-8.0.0-M2\webapps\host-manager
24-Jun-2019 15:05:48.927 INFO [Thread-16] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: C:\toolsx\apache-tomee-microprofile-8.0.0-M2\webapps\manager
24-Jun-2019 15:05:48.994 INFO [Thread-16] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: C:\toolsx\apache-tomee-microprofile-8.0.0-M2\webapps\ROOT
24-Jun-2019 15:05:49.090 INFO [Thread-16] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: C:\toolsx\apache-tomee-microprofile-8.0.0-M2\webapps\jjwtrest-1.0.0
24-Jun-2019 15:05:49.193 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
24-Jun-2019 15:05:49.199 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Jun-2019 15:05:49.204 INFO [Thread-16] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.stop Stopping server services
24-Jun-2019 15:05:49.225 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
24-Jun-2019 15:05:49.229 INFO [Thread-16] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```